# Convert "strange" ternary operator from java-script to python

Tags: javascript, python, if-statement, ternary-operator

I am converting a code from java-script (I am beginner) to python (intermediate level). The code involves an if statement under the form of a Conditional (ternary) Operator.

The line of code is this:

```
// if dLon over 180° take shorter rhumb line across the anti-meridian:
if (Math.abs(Δλ) > Math.PI) Δλ = Δλ>0 ? -(2*Math.PI-Δλ) : (2*Math.PI+Δλ);
```

I know the [definition of ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) which is the following:

> condition ? expr1 : expr2

However, my code as an extra "condition" which I don't know how to interpret: `Δλ = Δλ>0`

At the moment my python version looks like this:

```
import numpy as np
# note: delta_lon = Δλ
if np.abs(delta_lon) > np.pi:
            delta_lon = -(2*np.pi - delta_lon)
        else:
            delta_lon = 2*np.pi + delta_lon
```

but it seems to give wrong results. I guess the issue is given by the "condition" mentioned previously and by the fact I am redefining the variable `delta_lon`.

The entire code can be found under the section rhumb line distance in this [link](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html).

**EDIT:**
here is the complete code I am trying to convert from javascript:

```
var Δψ = Math.log(Math.tan(Math.PI/4+φ2/2)/Math.tan(Math.PI/4+φ1/2));
var q = Math.abs(Δψ) > 10e-12 ? Δφ/Δψ : Math.cos(φ1); // E-W course becomes ill-conditioned with 0/0

// if dLon over 180° take shorter rhumb line across the anti-meridian:
if (Math.abs(Δλ) > Math.PI) Δλ = Δλ>0 ? -(2*Math.PI-Δλ) : (2*Math.PI+Δλ);

var dist = Math.sqrt(Δφ*Δφ + q*q*Δλ*Δλ) * R;
```

I was able to convert almost the whole code except the if statement previously mentioned. If I do not write the statement, my python code returns the same result as the javascript code (which is ok just because I am using good input values...). However if I add the lines that I presented above, I do not get the same result anymore, which indicates that the ternary operator has been translated in the wrong way.

Comment: Your Python code looks OK to me actually.  Can you elaborate on what is "wrong" with your results?

Comment: From which library does `np.pi` come, and why aren't you using the `math` library?

Comment: well in python I usually use numpy as np.... therefore 3.14 = np.pi.... I could use math lib as well but it shouldn't matter that much right?

Comment: I'm asking because maybe there is a difference in the precision of `PI` being used by JS and your Python library.  How off are your numbers?  Do they at least correlate well with the JS numbers?

Comment: if I do not use the if statement that I proposed, the results are almost identical (9804.88324 vs 9804.88323)... I f I add the if statement, my results is wrong by thousands of unites (9804.88324 vs 42456.624004)... I don't think that pi is the error but more my implementation of the if statement... by writing it I should get the same result as well

Comment: I think your if else is correct, true to the logic of the original ternary expression, and that you're barking up the wrong tree.  There must be some other problems with your Python code/data.  From the link you included, the if else statement is part of a much larger formula.  You should check that entire formula for problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have misunderstood the intent of the code. Δλ should only be modified if it is outside [-pi, pi], and then moved in different directions depending on its sign. Translating the javascript code gives

```
if np.abs(delta_lon) > np.pi:
    delta_lon = -(2*np.pi - delta_lon) if delta_lon > 0 else 2*np.pi + delta_lon
```

alternatively you can do

```
if delta_lon > np.pi:
    delta_lon = -(2*np.pi - delta_lon)
elif delta_lon < -np.pi:
    delta_lon = 2*np.pi + delta_lon
```

which has the same effect.